# c++ member array not initialized

Tags: c++, initialization

I have the following constellation:

```
class base {...};

class derived : public base
{
public:
  unsigned int* a;

  derived(size_t num = 1) : a(0), _b(0)
  {
     a = new unsigned int[num];
     _b = new unsigned char[num];
  }
private:
  unsigned char* _b;
}
```

all is fine by doing this:

```
derived* instance = new derived();
```

but by doing this:

```
base* instance = new derived();
```

_b stays 0x0 and errors occur later when I try to use _b.

What is happening here?

Update:

The problem was caused by a Windows / Linux Cross platform issue - values were filled with incorrect pointers.

Comment: Post a test case or it didn't happen.

Comment: That's so strange it's difficult to believe. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Ideally something we could just paste to e.g. [ideone](http://ideone.com/) and see it ourselves.

Comment: Does base class have data member with name _b? You should show the base class definition.

Answer (score 2):

First:

Why do you need to initialize `a` and `b` twice? Use the explicit initialization only, or the standard member initialization only not both...

```
derived(size_t num = 1) : a(new unsigned int[num]), 
                          _b(new unsigned char[num])
{
}
```

This should do the trick.

Second: If you create an instance of `derived` into `base`, then all members and functions of derived will be useless. Except the members and functions of base, which is common in both classes.

Comment: **First**: this doesn't answer the question. **Second**: *"all members and functions of derived will be useless. Except the members and functions of base, which is common in both classes"* - have you heard about *virtual* functions?

Comment: Yes U are right I forget to answer the question. And I heard about virtual functions. And I forget them in my answer. My fault. :)